# Cannot assign to read only property '_canInitEmulator' of object '#<AuthImpl>' firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm using firebase for auth in my react app, and it always worked ok until this moment, when I try to log in or sign up it return this weird error

```
Cannot assign to read only property '_canInitEmulator' of object '#<AuthImpl>'
```

I searched online and most of the time the problem was the missing auth object that I've added. Here is the code

init.ts:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const app = initializeApp({
 apiKey: "AIzaSyBRPIzl7N-_zScT55HiM7UovWWIXsmTkoQ",
 authDomain: "bakery-59d9c.firebaseapp.com",
 projectId: "bakery-59d9c",
 storageBucket: "bakery-59d9c.appspot.com",
 messagingSenderId: "48986447422",
 appId: "1:48986447422:web:0afd00e42ebc06ab883b6f",
});

export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const firestore = getFirestore(app);
```

auth.ts

```
import { auth } from "./init";
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
} from "firebase/auth";

export async function loginWithEmailAndPassword(
  email: string,
  password: string
) {
  try {
    const user = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    return user;
  } catch (err: any) {
    throw new Error(err.message);
  }
}
```

Login.tsx

```
 async function login() {
   try {
      const loggedUser: any = await loginWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      setUser(loggedUser);
      toast.success("Logged in sucessfully", {
        position: "bottom-right",
      });
      navigate("/");
    } catch (err: any) {
      toast.error(err.message, {
        position: "bottom-right",
      });

      console.log(err.message)
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance